# Clone repository from github in xcode userid password error

Tags: xcode, git, github, git-clone

Open xcode then click "Connect to a repository"

[image]

After entering the URL the button on the bottom changes to clone. FYI The repository is private and should require a github password and userid. Clone button is then clicked.

[image]

It asks where to save the file. I choose a location then it comes here:
[image]

Always trust github.com is chosen as suggested in another post. Click Continue then get the following:

[image]

At this point it has not asked me for my username or password at any time. Looking around here and on other sites it should ask for user id and password at this point but this is all I get. 
How can I get to the screen asking me to enter my Github user id and password when cloning a private repository on github.com in xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a glitch in xCode. You will have to install git and repair/prepare the repository from the git command line or another git tool then reopen the project in xCode and then it will be recognized.

xCode is great for git when it works but will break sometimes and need manual repair/tweaking of a repository outside of xCode. You should think of the git features of xCode as a great aid to using git but not a complete interface replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You can try that way:

1. Open `Terminal` application.
2. cd to your project directory. (`cd /your/project/directory`)
3. Write `git clone https/link/for/your/git`.
4. Put `password` for the git user.
5. It will start download on your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work using the `git@github.com:user/repo.git` URL format if you have your [public SSH key set up properly on your Mac](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) (and the private key is not protected by a passphrase).

When xCode logs in via SSH to clone the repo, it will be able to do so without you having to provide any credentials. Note that this will probably only work where you have SSH (read/write) access to the repo in question. Since with Github you are likely to be forking another project and working on your own fork, this shouldn't be too much of an obstacle though.